# What is the correct way to show flash message in Zend Framework 2 Expressive

Tags: php, zend-framework, mezzio

I'd like to setup flash message(slim/flash). I saw the reference [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/cookbook/flash-messengers/).
I made the following middleware to register flash message.

```
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\DelegateInterface;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response\RedirectResponse;

function($request, DelegateInterface $delegate)
{
    $flash = $request->getAttribute('flash');
    $flash->addMessage('message', 'Hello World!');

    return new RedirectResponse('/other-middleware');
}
```

and the question is how to get this flash message from view templates?
The reference wrote here but I'm not sure where should I put this code and how to show the flash.

```
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\DelegateInterface;

function($request, DelegateInterface $delegate)
{
    $flash = $request->getAttribute('flash');
    $messages = $flash->getMessages();
    // ...
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in sentence below that block of code:

> From there, it's a matter of providing the flash messages to your template.

You need pass `$messages` to your view script in order to be able to render them.
Something like:

```
return new HtmlResponse(
  $this->renderer->render(
    $template,
    ['messages' => $messages]
  )
);
```